# Why are default comments deprecated?

Tags: comments, comment-form

I am developing a theme and, after calling comments_template(), noticed that "Theme without comments.php is deprecated since version 3.0".

I created a comments.php in the root of my theme and copied the default wp-includes/theme-compat/comments.php inside, which is perfectly fine for me. This core file will be removed in future versions of wordpress.

I am not sure if this is a good practice for theme development, though, as it is a complex bunch of code and it does not belong to the website development core features. I prefer wordpress to provide a default comments template.

I could deliver the theme without the ability to enable comments, but that is even worse.

I can be called lazy, but apart from that, shouldn't there be a standard/default comments template?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't copy *that* file, precisely because it is too bulky. About half of it is implementation of submission form, which was entirely replaced with [`comment_form()`](http://queryposts.com/function/comment_form/) function around that time.

So the answer why was it deprecated is roughly:

1. Newer code is more compact
2. Markup belongs in theme

For better and more relevant `comments.php` example look at core themes, such as [`twentyfifteen/comments.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/4.1/src/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/comments.php).

Comment: OK, so i will take comments.php of newest core themes as standard/base.
Thank you

Comment: I just wanted to throw a suggestion in to use [underscores](http://underscores.me/) as an excellent starter theme.

Comment: I switched to that style of comments.php but how do I login, that option seems gone.